# Confirming that a reverse ssh tunnel has been established

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, tunneling

I have a reverse ssh tunnel established between a client and a server computer. The client connects on the server on port 22, and creates a reverse ssh tunnel on port 4030.

After the client computer has created the tunnel, it will sent an email confirming the reverse ssh tunnel connection. I just need a command that will output something that proves that the reverse connection has been established, so I can include it in the email.

How can I do this?

Comment: `netstat -antep |grep 4030` will show whether port 4030 is being listened

Comment: running this on the client does not show any output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may run an `ss` command (the modern version of `netstat`) on the remote system:

```
 ssh me@remote ss -ntp | grep 4030
```

but better still you should use [autossh](http://www.harding.motd.ca/autossh/) (it exists on all distros). It checks automatically whether a reverse tunnel is operating and, after some user-defined amount of time without receiving pings has elapsed, automatically restarts the tunnel.

I start it at boot time, and it works perfectly over weeks, if not months.

Comment: I haven't really had a good experience with autossh. I tried ss and it works perfectly though. But what if port 4030 is already occupied by another client? Won't my client report that the tunnel is established?

Comment: @aristosv That's why I included the `-p` flag: it will tell you which process is using the port, solving the above problem.